# Code produced by GCC is 10 times slower than G++

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, g++, compiler-optimization

I am trying to compile a C++ project and have been asked to use GCC. This works fine and compiles without any problems, but the code generated by GCC is around ten times slower than that produced by G++ even with full optimizations.

Is this because GCC is meant for c-programs or can I do something to make the compiler optimize more?

This is the content in my makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -O3
SRC_PATH=Loki

FILES=bench.cpp bitboard.cpp evaluation.cpp magics.cpp main.cpp misc.cpp move.cpp movegen.cpp 
perft.cpp position.cpp psqt.cpp search.cpp thread.cpp transposition.cpp uci.cpp

SOURCES=$(FILES:%.cpp=$(SRC_PATH)/%.cpp)

OUTFILE=Loki.exe

all:
    gcc ${SOURCES} -o $(OUTFILE) ${CFLAGS}
```

Comment: ·`g++`  uses `CXXFLAGS` in [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Try `make -p`

Comment: If you run make with increased output verbosity, you can see what flags are been passed to the compiler, as @BasileStarynkevitch mentioned, you are likely missing optimisation flags when using GCC.

Comment: Does that mean i should just change the name "CFLAGS" to "CXXFLAGS"?

Comment: @BimmerBass: I recommend taking several hours to read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and the documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Comment: `and have been asked to use GCC` When you use the `g++` command, you are using the GCC compiler. You shouldn't use `gcc` command to compile C++ unless you know a good reason to do so.

Comment: How are you actually measuring the performance of the generated code?

Comment: The project is a chess engine in which I am measuring positions analyzed per second. Here g++ gives ~1.2 million whereas gcc gives <100k, although this was greatly increased by changing CFLAGS to CXXFLAGS.